# Why cant I load sys-proctable?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed the sys-proctable gem on a fresh Ubuntu image (running via Vagrant)
with Ruby 1.8.7.

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bunny (0.7.9)
chef (10.14.2)
...many, many gems more
sys-proctable (0.9.3 universal-linux)
systemu (2.5.2)
treetop (1.4.10)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

now I want to load it into **irb**

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'sys/proctable'
    LoadError: no such file to load -- sys/proctable
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

so what is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to require rubygems first. I think then it will work.

Also: are you sure you need to use a `/` and not a `-`?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you managed to load it...
Just wanted to make sure everything is written.

It's definitely a / that's required.
This should work :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sys/proctable'
....
```